# Invalid image url throws exception

Tags: symfony, routes, apache2

If I try to visit an invalid image url e.g. `example.com/images/non-existent-image` an error is thrown: `Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException`

How should I prevent this, is there a specific route(-requirement) I should add, or should I use something like a .htaccess rule?

Thanks

Comment: You should configure your web-server in such a way, that static data would **NOT** be requested via front controller (app.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the answer to this question is twofold.

First of all: Yes, static resources should not be requested via the front controller (as per thecatontheflat's comment). Symfony has a rule in the `.htaccess`file distributed with the standard edition:

```
# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
```

As it turned out, my problem was somewhere else. It is normal for symfony to throw the `ResouceNotFoundException`. However , this error should be caught and should create a 404 instead. This was not happening because I was using `IS_GRANTED`in my error template. (Also see stof's comment [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5225#issuecomment-7626407))

Answer (score 0):

If it was a permission error you would get sth like permission denies. Check again the path...also check that you have placed the folder images in the proper directory in server (try moving images/ in the same directory where directory WEB-INF is..files under WEB-INF cannot be accessed for security reasons)

Comment: Valid image urls work fine. The problem is that invalid image urls throw an error (500) instead of a 404

Comment: This means (see [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) that is an internal server error and it hasn't to do anything with the path given. What do you mean when you say an "invalid image"? corrupted? missing? sth else?

Comment: Invalid path, so a non-existing image. I know what the status codes mean. I think the /images path should not be handled by the symfony router (?). That what my question is about